# Notify deleter when post is being deleted, that comments/answers are being made on it

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers, self-delete

One of the most frustrating things on the SO sites is, when I'm typing a large comment (or answer), and then it won't post, because the Q or A has been deleted.  How about warning the deleter that someone is commenting (or answering) on his post?

Comment: This is a feature request. Is it status-completed or declined? I was going to ask a similar/related question today, but searched and found this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 This has happened a couple times to me in the past, and it definitely is rather frustrating.

Perhaps a 30 second interval while editing to check the status, and pop in our favorite orange-bar when there's a major change in status...

Comment: Yep, just happened to me on your last question.

Comment: @Lance: Sorry about that. Turned out it was a dupe, so I deleted it with haste! :)

Comment: But it looked like edits were still possible as you were deleting your post.

Answer (score 5):

This could be handy, but only if I can see what they're typing. If it's just a comment telling me what I already know (and what prompted me to delete the post in the first place...) then there's no reason I should wait around for them to finish writing it.

Such a feature would also allow me to preemptively respond to comments. Which could be fun.

Comment: Rename comments to blips and you might have something there.

Comment: @random: blips you say? Brilliant! Now we just need a hip new name for *posts*...

Comment: There's a wave of inspiration coming across here. Just can't quite... `JavaScript failed to load`