# Inform user that post is already deleted when writing comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, notifications, deleted-posts

OK, I hit this thrice today itself.

I was trying to write a comment under a particular post. After composing I clicked on the submit button, a pop up is shown saying this **post is deleted, locked or something else**.

Should there be a pop up saying "**No use of this comment. This post is a goner**" or something English , when I am writing the comment itself. Why wait until user finishes the entire composition process? I can pack up and go to next question, without wasting a precious minute.

P.S : I see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38209/168149), 3 year old question which is a feature request. It is neither status-completed and nor decined. It is somewhat related, but my suggestion is different. I couldn't find any other duplicates.

Comment: Might I inquire as to the sort of workflow that led you to hit this three times today?

Comment: Okay.. let me find the questions again..

Comment: @TimPost [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16829018/can-we-count-the-number-of-rows-generating-in-section-uicollectionview/16829127#16829127) is the most recent one. I was commenting under the deleted answer.

Comment: This is somewhat close to what I was composing  *1) Please add some description, code only answers are not encouraged 2) OP was asking about UICollectionView and you are answering about UITableView 3) Please learn how to format code*.. I had a link to a meta thread explaining how to format code in posts. So When I typed it in, clicked submit.. rest you know

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is not yet implemented because it's a very rare case. How many times it takes to compose a comment in general? 10- seconds? What are the chances that a post is deleted within that period of time considering that most of the comments comes towards the first minutes of life of a question and in that period only moderators can manually delete it? Near none.

The idea is nice though. The only problem I can see in implementing it is that you would work with very short timespans between two check-requests (request performed to check the state of the question) which can be... *dangerous*.

Comment: well has to disagree with you one some points. First,  not everyone will be able to type a comment in 10 second, in cases when you need to hyperlink and format. Second, we are not only talking about questions. An user can delete his answer anytime as far as I know.

Comment: @Krishnabhadra, 1) well yes, that was an average. 2) I have to agree with you on that.